# Selecting certain XML tags with criterion matching other tags

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an XML file with a structure like the following:

```
<text>
  <dialogue>
     <pattern>
        We're having a {nice|great} time.
     </pattern>
     <criterion>
       <!-- match this tag, get the above pattern -->
        average_person, tourist, delighted
     </criterion>
  </dialogue>
     <pattern>
        The service {here stinks|is terrible}!
     </pattern>
     <criterion>
        tourist, disgruntled, average_person
     </criterion>
  <dialogue>
     <pattern>
        They have {smoothies|funny hats}. Neat!
     </pattern>
     <criterion>
        tourist, smoothie_enthusiast
     </criterion>
  </dialogue>
  <dialogue>
     <pattern>
        I wonder how {expensive|valuable} these resort tickets are?
     </pattern>
     <criterion>
        merchant, average_person
     </criterion>
  </dialogue>
</text>
```

What I would like to do is go through the `dialogue` tags, look at the `criterion` tag, and match a list of words. If they match, I would then like to use the pattern in that `dialogue` tag. I'm using Python for this task.

What I'm currently doing is walking through the tags by utilizing an `lxml` "etree" which looks like this:

```
tree = etree.parse('tourists.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
g=0
for i in root.iterfind('dialogue/criterion'):
   a = i.text.split(',')
   # The "personality" variable has a value like "delighted" or "disgruntled".
   # "tags_to_match" are the criterion that we want to, well, match. It may
   # have criterion like "merchant", "tourist", or "delighted".
   # When the tags match (in the "match_tags" function) returns true, it
   # appends the pattern to the "tourist_patterns" list.
   if personality is not 'average_person' and match_tags( tags_to_match, a):
       tourist_patterns.append(root[g][0].text)
   g+=1
# When we don't have a match, we just go with the "average_person" tag.
if len(tourist_patterns) == 0:
   # Go through the tags again, choosing the ones that match the
   # 'average_person' personality and put it in the "tourist_patterns" list.
```

I then go through the elements in the "tourist_patterns" list and pluck out what I want.

I'm trying to simplify this. How can I go through the tags, match the text I want in the `criterion` tags, and then take the pattern in the `pattern` tags? I've also been trying to set a default for when the criterion isn't matched (hence the "average_person" personality criterion).

---

**Edit:** Some commentators asked for the list of what to match. Basically, I  would want it to match some or all of the words in the `criterion` tags, and it would give the text in the `pattern` tag underneath that `dialogue` tag. So if I was looking for "tourist" and "smoothie_enthusiast", it would get one match in my XML example. I would then like to get the `pattern` tag text "They have {smoothies|funny hats}. Neat!". If that fails to match any of the words in `criterion` tags, I would just try to match "average_person" and "tourist".

In turn, `tourist_patterns` would look like this when it matches:

```
>>> tourist_pattern
    ['They have {smoothies|funny hats}. Neat!']
```

And when it doesn't match, it would match this:

```
>>> tourist_pattern
    ['They have {smoothies|funny hats}. Neat!', 'The service {here stinks|is terrible}!']
```

Hope that clears things up.

Comment: Please show desired output and what is in *tourist_patterns* so we can reproduce code.

Comment: You said that criterion tag should match a list of words. Can you give an example of that list of words? For example, if in criterion tag is `average_person, tourist, delighted` for some list of words what does mean that they match?

Comment: I have updated my question with more information.

Comment: Look up `xpath` (the general form of your xpath query will be like: `/foo[../bar=...]`) ... note that everybody use xpath 1.0, not 2.0 or 3.0.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @o11c. I've looked up xpath, but the syntax (at least for what I want) mystified me. Also, I wonder why everyone else uses xpath 1.0?

Comment: @Ertain because the only open-source implementation of later versions is in Java, but C is the universal language. Note also: if you use xpath within XSLT it is much more powerful - e.g. you can define variables.